# system() copy fails, while cmd copy works

Tags: c, copy, system, command, escaping

In cmd.exe, I can execute the command "copy c:\hello.txt c:\hello2.txt" and it worked fine.
But in my C program, I ran this piece of code and got the following error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("copy c:\hello.txt c:\hello2.txt");
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
The system cannot find the file specified.

Anybody know what is going on here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Inside C strings (and quite a few other languages that use the same escaping rules), `\` should be `\\` since it's the escape character. It allows you to enter, in normal text, non-printable characters such as:

- the tab character `\t`.
- the carriage-return character `\r`.
- the newline character `\n`.
- others which I won't cover in detail.

Since `\` is used as the escape character, we need a way to put an *actual* `'\'` into a string. This is done with the sequence `\\`.

Your line should therefore be:

```
system("copy c:\\hello.txt c:\\hello2.txt");
```

This can sometimes lead to obscure errors with commands like:

```
FILE *fh = fopen ("c:\text.dat", "w");
```

where the `\t` is actually the `tab` character and the file that you're trying to open is:

            <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, all the Windows functions support Unix style slashes

```
system("copy c:/hello.txt c:/hello2.txt");
```

Some people prefer this since it's easier to spot an odd '\'.
But it might confuse Windows users if you display this path in a message.