# Make a compiled exe copy itself to desktop in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I'm trying to write an app that will copy itself to desktop after it's run. I could do this in C# like this:

`String fileName = String.Concat(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, ".exe");
String filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileName);
File.Copy(filePath, Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), fileName));`

Is there a way to achieve similar functionality in c++?

Comment: `argv[0]` (from main) to get the name of the executable, then use something like [`boost::filesystem`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) to copy the file.

Comment: Use [system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237703/system-copy-fails-while-cmd-copy-works) to perform the calls, and the token for the desktop should be `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` along with argv[0] as stated above.

Comment: yes there is , for the path manipulation ones you do it yourself with string manipulation. For the file copy , that just maps down to win32 calls. Same for the environment query. Look at the source code of the c# calls https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: For best performance, use an OS API that copies files.

Comment: as you can see here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,4a0905e7dc32d77d , c# runtime uses win32 api CopyFile https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile